# Check if 2 numbers are within 1% of each other

Tags: java, math, comparison

```
    public static double squareRoot(double num) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
        if (num < 0.0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Number cannot be negative.");
        double guess = num / 2.0, pastGuess;
        guess = 0.5 * (guess + (num / guess));

        do {
            pastGuess = guess;
            guess = 0.5 * (guess + (num / guess));
           } while ((pastGuess / guess) >= 1.01);// run until both numbers are within 1% of each other
        return guess; // return square root of num
    }
```

im trying to implement a simple squareRoot method using the babylonian algorithm. my problem is that for numbers less then 0.01, the result is very inaccurate.

i want the loop to run until both numbers (pastGuess and guess) are within 1% if each other, but i cant figure out the proper math for it.

i came up with:

```
((pastGuess / guess) >= 1.01)
```

i also tryed:

```
((pastGuess / guess) >= 1.01 || (guess / pastGuess ) >= 1.01)
```

this works abit better but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: what about check for 0.99 for the case when pastGuess is smaller than guess?

Comment: Have you tried `ABS(pastGuess - guess) > 0.0000001` or something of this sort?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case where only the smaller number is within one percent of the larger, but not the other way around IE. `99` and `100`. `99` is within 1% of `100`, but `100` is not within 1% of `99`

Comment: yes ABS(pastGuess - guess) > 0.0000001 works but this is not 1% difference.

Comment: what is the range of values that num can be.because the perfect way is depends on that

Comment: What is the problem? You stop when the difference between the current and previous guess drops below 1%, so the results you get are roughly between 0.01% and 0.000001% off. If you are unlucky and hit the larger end, that's of course not too good, but that's for both, numbers larger than 1 and smaller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
double ratio = pastGuess / guess;
(ratio >= 1.01 || ratio <= 0.99)
```

Note that I used `0.99` for readability. The correct value for the verification above to be symmetric would be a constant equal to `(100/101) = 0.99009900...`

Comment: +1 actually I think your approach is probably better than mine 'cause multiplication and division are usually bit more stable/precise than a subtraction.

Answer (score 4):

Guess you want 99% too, so basically it means that the difference is less than 1%:

```
Math.abs((pastGuess - guess) / guess) < 0.01
```

This should be already quite stable.

Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

```
float parcent = Math.abs(1f - (pastGuess / guess))

if(parcent <= 0.01f)
```

:D

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the two numbers are 'a' and 'b'. Let's say a < b.

1% of 'b' = b/100

1% of 'a' = a/100

So 'a' is within 1% of 'b' if a > b-b/100 or (b-a)/b < 1/100

And 'b' is within 1% of 'a' if b < a+a/100 or (b-a)/a < 1/100.

Since a< b it implies  (b-a)/b < (b-a)/a

So if (b-a)/a < 1/100 it implies that (b-a)/b < 1/100 as (b-a)/b is smaller than (b-a)/a.

So the check simply can be:

`abs(guess-pastguess)/ ((guess < pastguess) ? guess : pastguess) < 0.01 ;`

Let's look at an example:

If a=99.001 and b=100 then b=100 is not within 1 % of a=99  1% of 99.001 is .99001 so b has to be less than 99.99001

On the other hand b=99.0001 is within 1% of a=100 as 1% of 100 is 0.1. So any number greater than 99 is within 1% of 100.